# Drill down into table - fields for display

Tags: splunk

I've created a dashboard which contains a summary table for which I want to have a drill down into a second table which shows the events related to that summary record.

I have the drill down working and displaying the rows needed, however it is displaying all fields for that event rather than the specific ones I've set. 
If I run the search query on its own through the Search app, or separately on a dashboard it displays the appropriate fields.

This is the macro search code

```
source="MySource" EventClass="MyStep" $Transaction$ | dedup StepName | convert ctime(_time) as Date| table StepName, Date, EventStatus, Timing.
```

Here is the XML for the dashboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view refresh="900" template="dashboard.html">
    <label>Synthetics Dashboard</label>
    <module name="AccountBar" layoutPanel="appHeader" />
    <module name="AppBar" layoutPanel="navigationHeader" />
    <module name="Message" layoutPanel="messaging">
        <param name="filter">*</param>
        <param name="clearOnJobDispatch">False</param>
        <param name="maxSize">1</param>
    </module>
    <module name="HiddenSearch" layoutPanel="panel_row1_col1" group="Sythetic Transaction Recent Status" autoRun="True">
        <param name="search">
            synthetics_transactionStatus(SyntheticTransaction)</param>
        <module name="SimpleResultsTable">
            <param name="displayRowNumbers">off</param>
            <param name="drilldown">row</param>
            <module name="HiddenSearch" layoutPanel="panel_row2_col1" group="Login Timing Last 4hrs">
                <param name="search">synthetics_transactionSteps($Transaction$)</param>
                <module name="ConvertToIntention">
                    <param name="intention">
                        <param name="name">stringreplace</param>
                        <param name="arg">
                            <param name="Transaction">
                                <param name="value">$click.value$</param>
                            </param>
                        </param>
                    </param>
                    <module name="ConvertToDrilldownSearch">
                        <module name="SimpleResultsTable">
                            <param name="displayRowNumbers">off</param>
                            <param name="drilldown">row</param>
                        </module>
                    </module>
                </module>
            </module>
        </module>
    </module>
</view>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way around this, I had to explicitly specify fields within the second SimpleResultsTable module e.g.

```
<module name="SimpleResultsTable">
<param name="fields">StepName, Date, EventSeverity, Timing</param>
<param name="displayRowNumbers">off</param>
<param name="drilldown">row</param>...
```